# .click on a child div but do not trigger click on parentDiv?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/js5LR/1/

Basically, how can I have a .click event on a Child element but not a Parent element?

So clicking the inner div should not fire the .click event for the parent div.

CSS:

```
.parentDiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.childDiv {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="parentDiv">
    <div id="child" class="childDiv">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$('#parent').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked the parent!');
}
);
$('#child').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked the child!');
}
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: just for the record: why would you give the parent and the child a click event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('#child').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('You clicked the child!');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/js5LR/4/)**

Your click event bubbles up the DOM, and [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) will prevent that.

You could also just return false:

```
$('#child').click(function () {
    alert('You clicked the child!');
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gYgq8/)**

Comment: Wow thank you, I never knew that existed and not experienced that in the DOM before but of course it makes sense. Its solved my issue perfectly after long frustration! I will have a read up on that. Thanks! Will accept your answer when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

You just need to stop propagation of the child click - http://jsfiddle.net/js5LR/3/

```
$('#child').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('You clicked the child!');
}
```